# Can't open a file on python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I have been struggling opening a file on python. I am not sure why I can't open the file and why this is showing two // while I just put only one in code.
And this is saying

---

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-82-40719067ea74> in <module>
----> 1 train_data = create_train_data()

<ipython-input-79-414ab1fcfe22> in create_train_data()
      1 def create_train_data():
  2     train_data = []
----> 3     for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
  4         label = label_img(img)
  5         path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR ,img)

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label 
syntax is incorrect: 'D:\\Dog vs cat\\dogs-vs-cats\train'
```

I have already checked if I have tqdm.

```
enter code here
from tqdm import tqdm

TRAIN_DIR = 'D:\Dog vs cat\dogs-vs-cats\train'

def create_train_data():
    train_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR ,img)
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
        (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(label)])

        shufle(training_data)
        np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
    return training_data
    train_data = create_train_data()
```

I would like this to actually open the file.

Comment: Try using double quotes to wrap TRAIN_DIR i.e. TRAIN_DIR = "D:\Dog vs cat\dogs-vs-cats\train"

Comment: I tired that too but returned me the same. Of course, I typed shift and enter to run the double quoted program. I am not sure why "" is not reflected in the error comment though.
TRAIN_DIR = "D:\Dog vs cat\dogs-vs-cats\train"
TEST_DIR = "D:\Dog vs cat\dogs-vs-cats\test"   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\\Dog vs cat\\dogs-vs-cats\train'

Comment: Thank you everyone who answered. I have noticed that I had to use thrash and should not use space.

Comment: And yet, I have encountered a new problem. So, I think this time, it recognizes the file, however, it stays a 0% and the estimate time is weird.                                                                              
 0%|          | 0/25001 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Comment: Even though you have fixed the file syntax so that it's accepted by the package, it may not actually correspond to the files in your machine. Can you do some print dumps on the `path` variable and see if that is really the path of your input images?

Comment: I am sorry, I had some syntax error. I fixed it and started running till 50% where I get stuck again saying    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-40719067ea74> in <module>
----> 1 train_data = create_train_data()

<ipython-input-18-a8c56d5d5e00> in create_train_data()
      2     training_data = []
      3     for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
----> 4         label = label_img(img)
      5         path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)
      6         img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

Comment: <ipython-input-17-7008e8ec6b10> in label_img(img)
      1 def label_img(img):
----> 2     word_label = img.split('.')[-3]
      3     # conversion to one-hot array [cat,dog]
      4     #                            [much cat, no dog]
      5     if word_label == 'cat': return [1,0]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: please don't paste code/ error messages into comments, they're not readable. either edit them into your question or ask a new question